# Continuous functions dense in $L_1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

If $X$ is a complete doubling metric space equipped with a complete probability measure $\mu$ such that all Borel sets are $\mu$-measurable, then $C_c(X)$ --- the continuous functions with compact support --- are dense in $L_1(\mu)$.

Question: What are the weakest conditions under which $C_c(X)$ is dense in $L_1(\mu)$ for non-doubling (i.e., infinite doubling dimensional) metric spaces?

Comment: Do you want to assume regularity of the measure?

Comment: Do nice things follow from that assumption alone? What else does one need to assume?

Comment: I have the feeling that regularity might do the trick, however it might be to strong an assumption as I do not know your purpose. Have no time at the moment, shall think about this later.

Comment: Great, very much looking forward!

Comment: Regularity of the measure won't solve the problem by itself.  On a Polish space all probability measures are regular, but for instance if $X$ is a separable Banach space then $C_c(X) = 0$.  Typically one assumes local compactness to ensure that $C_c(X)$ is sufficiently rich.

Comment: And I think it's sufficient to have $X$ locally compact and $\mu$ Radon, the latter of which will happen automatically if $X$ is additionally separable.  That should be standard textbook stuff, and no doubling assumptions needed.  Is that the sort of thing you are looking for, or do you have other examples in mind?

Comment: Local compactness is exactly what I'm trying to get away from!

Comment: Also I didn't understand Nate's comment about $C_c=0$.

Comment: @AryehKontorovich In an *infinite dimensional* Banach space, an open ball is not precompact, and the support of a nonzero continuous function contains some open ball, so it is not compact. I'm not sure what separable had to do with anything.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, I should have said "infinite dimensional" (adding "separable" just guarantees that any measure is Radon).  By the way, local compactness is hard to avoid: suppose $X$ is not locally compact at some point $x$; then every $f \in C_c(X)$ vanishes at $x$.  So if you take $\mu = \delta_x$ to be a point mass at $X$, you find that $C_c(X)$ is not dense in $L^1(\mu)$.

Comment: I see. So local compactness is pretty much indispensable.

Comment: Indeed.  Usually when you don't have local compactness, you look for a different space of "test functions" other than $C_c(X)$.  For instance, in analysis on Banach spaces $X$, one commonly considers "cylinder functions", which are of the form $F(x) = \varphi(f_1(x), \dots, f_n(x))$ for $f_i \in X^*$ and $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  These are dense in $L^1(X,\mu)$ if $X$ is separable.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a metric-space analog of these?

Comment: For a generic metric space?  I mean, you can always use the bounded continuous functions, or bounded Lipschitz functions, or something like that.  But something like cylinder functions, that's going to depend on additional structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like in Nate's comment, you need locally compactness. Assuming that, if $\mu$ is regular, then $C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^1(\mu)$. 
For the proof: For a compact subset $K$ there exists a sequence $f_n$ in $C_c(X)$ with $f_n\ge 1_K$ and $\int f_n\,d\mu\to \mu(K)$. Therefore, $1_K$ lies in the closure of $C_c(X)$ in $L^1$. By another approximation, $1_A$ lies in this closure for every measurable $A$. This suffices.

Answer (score 0):

I see the question got upvoted, so I'll post a brief note explaining how we got around the local compactness for our application, in case anyone else finds it useful. In Lemma A.1 of [Hanneke, Kontorovich, Sabato, and Weiss - Universal Bayes consistency in metric spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.09855), we prove that for every metric probability space, the collection of Lipschitz functions is dense in $L_1$. The result may be known or folklore, but it was *exactly* the analogue of $C_c$ that we needed.